# React-native Expo: Invariant Violation: View config not found for name

Tags: react-native, expo

I was trying a module located on npm on snack.expo.

But the following error is given to me.

```
Invariant Violation: View config not found for name RNMaterialLetterIcon
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Link: https://snack.expo.io/SyZa8lUEQ

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import RNMaterialLetterIcon from 'react-native-material-letter-icon';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <RNMaterialLetterIcon
      size={80}
      border={true}
      borderColor={"#dd2c00"}
      borderSize={2}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

Comment: @Harrison: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Comment: ok my mistake, scratch what I said. Is RNMaterialLetterIcon a icon package? If so you need to declare what icon you are using. so in `<RNMaterialLetterIcon />` you need to include a `name = 'someIcon'`

Comment: No it is not.
I think it's a problem of snack.expo, which does not allow to run modules that have parts written in native, but I'm not sure.